# How to draw a pixel array over an existing texture using OpenGL ES

Tags: android, arrays, opengl-es, textures, pixel

I am trying to draw a pixel array, which contains alpha values (it is supposed to be a grayscale picture) on a texture in OpenGL ES on Android.

**Background information**

The pixel array is generated by FreeType 2, I have checked the contents of the array and it looks OK to me.

So for each letter FreeType 2 generates, I need to draw it on the screen. In case you want to know it more specifically, it is the bootanimation. And I want to draw a text over the animation.

**Current result**

This is what I get:

**IMPORTANT:** i have removed the white boxes as explained in **Edit 4** but I still don't get any letters.

[image: result]

The white squares are supposed to be letters.

**Code snippet for drawing the pixel buffers of the letters:**

```
void BootAnimation::drawFtBitmap(FT_Bitmap *bitmap, int, int) {
    int width = abs(bitmap->pitch);
    int height = bitmap->rows;
    /*// Round up to power of 2
    width--;
    width |= width >> 1;
    width |= width >> 2;
    width |= width >> 4;
    width |= width >> 8;
    width |= width >> 16;
    width++;
    height--;
    height |= height >> 1;
    height |= height >> 2;
    height |= height >> 4;
    height |= height >> 8;
    height |= height >> 16;
    height++;*/
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glTexEnvx(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &mBootStatusTex.name);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBootStatusTex.name);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA,
                    width, height,
                    0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap->buffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &mBootStatusTex.name);
}
```

**Additional information and explanation**

`mBootStatusTex` is a `Texture`.

The array is a unsigned byte array.
The size of the array is set by `bitmap->pitch * bitmap->rows`.
`bitmap->pitch` can be seen as the width of the image, but using `bitmap->width` wouldn't make a difference in this case.

I am a beginner in OpenGL ES, I never did anything like this before. My goal is to draw text which has a specific font on top of the animation.

The problem is simply that instead of getting text, I just get those white boxes.

**What I have tried**

I have tried removing glDrawTexiOES, but then it doesn't show anything.

I tried using both `GL_ALPHA` and `GL_LUMINANCE`, both same result.

And much more...

If you need more information, please let me know. I hope the code above is enough.

**Edit:** The height and width is wrong. Because I round it up. I shiuld better use some kind of crop or something. But that doesn't fix the problem with the white boxes.

**Edit 2:** The problem is that it does not draw anything. I pass the array, it **has** various values but nothing is drawn on the screen. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit 3:** I checked the error code for each and every call. No errors.

**Edit 4:** I updated the code above. Still not working. I removed the `glDrawTexiOES` call because the only thing it does is drawing solid boxes. `glTexImage2D` is not drawing anything yet. At least I can't see it. Even if I round the size up to power of 2, it doesn't work. In the updated code above you can see how I am trying to use mipmaps. That way it should handle it automatically. Also tried using `glSubTexImage2D`. Doesn't work.

**Edit 5:** I also don't know how to set the position of the texture. Would the following (pseudo-code like) snippet work?

```
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

**Edit 6:** I also tried (just as an experiment) drawing each and every single pixel using `glDrawTexiOES`. While it works fine for a few drawings, it doesn't for the all the buffers. If i draw the complete text, it is distorted for the most part and the whole screen has random colors. So this isn't a way to go.
Also tried overlaying the surface with another, but transparent surface, but it doesn't work too. I discarded my changes since this isn't working how I wanted. I just wanted a simple way of drawing text on top of that bootanimation.